# How to shift button's text to another button's text when it clicked

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrOmO.jpg)Make simple puzzle game with numbers buttons place 4x4. when button pressed it should change text with diagonal button's text. I did shuffle numbers. I've problem with shifting button's text.
This is code for 4x4 puzzle game.

here my code

```
private LinearLayout buttonsContainer;
private Button[][] buttons = new Button[4][4];
private Button restartButton;
private List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonsContainer = findViewById(R.id.buttonsContainer);
    restartButton = findViewById(R.id.restartButton);
    restartButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        LinearLayout rows = (LinearLayout) buttonsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = (Button) rows.getChildAt(j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        numberList.add(i);
    }
    restartGame();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.restartButton: {
            restartGame();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.buttonsContainer:{

            break;
        }
    }
}

private void restartGame() {
    Collections.shuffle(numberList);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(i==3 && j==3)continue;
            buttons[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(numberList.get(4*i+j)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code first

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
String s = button1.getText();
button1.setText(button3.getText());
button3.setText(s);
```

When button is clicked.